# Make change width of div content in many different positions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want take width of div content depend on width of each parent div outside.

I have HTML like :

```
<div class="box-outside1">
<div class="box1">
    <div class="post-thumnail79"></div>
</div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="box-outside5">
<div class="box1">
    <div class="post-thumnail79"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Class `box-outside1` and `box-outside5` have different `width`.

And class `box1` is set with value of `width` is 100%

That mean depending on width of class `box-outsideN`, we will set width for class `post-thumnail79`.

I presented but It set for all class `post-thumnail79`.

You can see Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kMBUT/1/) and help me for solving it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMBUT/5/)

```
$(".box1").each(function (index, element){
    var intBoxWidth = $(this).width();

    if(intBoxWidth > 400 && intBoxWidth < 500) {
        $(".post-thumnail79", this).width(intBoxWidth / 2);
    }
    else if(intBoxWidth < 300){
        $(".post-thumnail79", this).width(intBoxWidth);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check my jsfiddle with condition and take your answer again. Thanks

Comment: +1 for doing above and beyond for someone who has shown no effort to do it on their own.

Comment: I am checking. Thank you.

Comment: Just updated - take that latest code up there! Also, see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMBUT/5/)

Comment: Of course. I always highly appreciate for enthusiastic people. I learned more with your help. And check for best answers is necessary.